# how can i assign value to textbox in MVC - Sharepoint Provider-hosted

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sharepoint, provider-hosted

I want to get and assign value to my textbox from controller.

here is my textbox:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="RegardingTo" name="RegardingTo" value="??????"/>
```

then i want to get the value from this action.

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int? RequestID)
    {

        if (RequestID <= 0)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        var ReqID = db.usp_RequestGetDetails(RequestID);
        if (ReqID == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        return View();
    }
```

please help :)

Comment: i'm trying to pass this model @model uRequestWeb.Models.usp_RequestGetDetails_Result

Comment: but  when you `return View()` you don't pass it any `Model` like what @Smit Patel has showed you `return View(quote)`

Comment: @jaimedanq i tried this return View(ReqID); but i got an error

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can assign value to the textbox using Model, First of all create a model then link that model with your view. And In Controller assign the value to model and return to the view.

Or At runtime if you want to assign the value to your text box then you can use Ajax call to your controller and get the value.

Please revert in case of any query.

Comment: thanks for the Suggestion..can you give some link regarding to this what you suggest?i'm just a newbie..

Answer (score 0):

See what i am doing to do the same, Make a custom model with your relevant fields, then assign values to them in `controller`, and pass this values to `View`, And that's it. :)

**Custom Model**

```
public partial class QuoteParameter
{
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> TripStartDateLimit { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> TripEndDateLimit { get; set; }     
    public int PolicyId { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{            
    QuoteParameter quote = new QuoteParameter();
    quote.TripEndDateLimit = DateTime.Now;
    quote.TripEndDateLimit = DateTime.Now;
    quote.PolicyId = 5;
    return View(quote);                     
}
```

**View**

```
@model EHIC.Models.Models.QuoteParameter
```

**By Razor syntax**

```
<div class="row-fluid span12">
      <div class="span4">
           <p><strong>Trip Start Date Limit :</strong></p>
      </div>
      <div class="span5">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TripStartDateLimit, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Policy StartDate Limit", @required = true })
      </div>
</div>

<div class="row-fluid span12">
      <div class="span4">
           <p><strong>Trip End Date Limit :</strong></p>
      </div>
      <div class="span5">
           @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TripEndDateLimit, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Policy EndDate Limit", @required = true })
      </div>
</div>
```

**By HTML Code**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="TripStartDateLimit" name="TripStartDateLimit" value="@Model.TripStartDateLimit"/>

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="TripEndDateLimit" name="TripEndDateLimit" value="@Model.TripEndDateLimit"/>
```

> EDIT

By Click on this button you can send the `PolicyId`(as an example) to controller, and then you can do whatever you want there..!!!

```
<a href='../../controller/Edit?PolicyId=@Models.PolicyId'>
   <span title='Edit'></span>
</a>

@Html.ActionLink("Edit","Edit", new { id = item.RequestID })
```

You can find the PolicyId which you sent from the Edit Page..

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{            
    //Get your data from Store_procedure..
    return View();                     
}
```

Comment: thanks for your comment, i mean here is on the Edit action of my controller,I need the value of the RequestID to put all its value to the textbox. is this possible? i'm using a Stored procedure to select all the value of the said ID

Comment: this is how I get the ID  @Html.ActionLink("Edit","Edit", new { id = item.RequestID })

Comment: Yes, so change Controller Action to Get the id into it, in example change PolicyId to id

Comment: By using this you can 100% get an id into controller edit method, if the type of `item.RequestID` is `int`

Comment: Yes I got the ID by using this @Html.ActionLink("Edit","Edit", new { id = item.RequestID }) but i got this error The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult`1[uRequestWeb.Models.usp_RequestGetDetails_Result]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'uRequestWeb.Models.usp_RequestGetDetails_Result'.

Comment: Check with the Static code by Put `new { id = 2}` and let me know it will work or not?

Comment: but when i try to insert this textbox: @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RegardingTo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } }) same error show..

Comment: Can you explain me your Flow?, What you need from Controller to View

Comment: In index.cshtml, I have a table that data is from @foreach (var item in Model) then, it has an edit button at the end of every <tr> using this @Html.ActionLink("Edit","Edit", new { id = item.RequestID }). but in my edit.cshtml for, i want to use the storedProcedure to display the select ID values.that those values will be the value of every textbox in my edit.cshml form

Comment: Check out this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20941017/mvc-net-edit-button-choose-right-method