# MVC Web Api difference between HttpPost and HttpPut

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm new to MVC Web Api.

I want to have two different methods.

PUT `localhost/api/user` - to modify a user

POST `localhost/api/user` - to add a user

So my `ApiController` looks like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public bool user(userDTO postdata)
    {
        return dal.addUser(postdata);
    }

    [HttpPut]
    public bool user(userDTO postdata)
    {
        return dal.editUser(postdata);
    }
```

However my `HttpPut` method says "already defines a member called user with the same parameter types.

Shouldn't the `[HttpPost]` and `[HttpPut]` make the methods unique?

Comment: The restriction is a fundamental part of C#, you can't have two methods with the same name and arguments. Attributes have no say on that, neither does MVC.

Comment: Refer to here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9552761/get-and-post-methods-with-the-same-action-name-in-the-same-controller for a potential solution

Comment: decorate your action method with both the types.                                          eg [HttpPost] in the next line [HttpPut]
    public bool user(userDTO postdata)
    {
        return dal.addUser(postdata);
    }

Comment: Related post - [What is the difference between POST and PUT in HTTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/630453/465053)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> MVC Web Api difference between HttpPost and HttpPut

An HTTP `PUT` is supposed to accept the body of the request, and then store that at the resource identified by the `URI`.

An HTTP `POST` is more general. It is supposed to initiate an action on the server. That action could be to store the request body at the resource identified by the `URI`, or it could be a different URI, or it could be a different action.

PUT is like a file upload. A put to a URI affects exactly that URI. A POST to a URI could have any effect at all.

> already defines a member called user with the same parameter types

You can't have multiple methods with the same signature within the same scope like that i.e. same return type and parameter type.

```
[HttpPost]
public bool User(userDTO postdata)
{
    return dal.addUser(postdata);
}

[HttpPut]
[ActionName("User")]
public bool UserPut(userDTO postdata)
{
    return dal.editUser(postdata);
}
```

more related ans. check this .  [GET and POST methods with the same Action name in the same Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9552761/get-and-post-methods-with-the-same-action-name-in-the-same-controller)

Answer (score 8):

No attribute can make your methods unique when you have 2 methods with the same name and the same signature.

The solution in your case would look something like this.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public bool User(userDTO postdata)
    {
        return dal.addUser(postdata);
    }

    [HttpPut]
    [ActionName("User")]
    public bool UserPut(userDTO postdata)
    {
        return dal.editUser(postdata);
    }
```

P.S: The convention for naming methods is that you should use PascalCase and use verbs when naming your methods.

[Method Naming Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4df752aw(v=vs.71).aspx)