# Same method in controller accept GET and POST

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have this URL: localhost:44302/api/SendMessage

Where it needs to work with GET and POST at the same time, so

```
localhost:44302/api/SendMessage/?destination=something@email.com&message=helloworld
```

needs to work the same way that a ajax POST can work too.

Right now the Method it's like this:

```
 [Route("[controller]/[action]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class apiController : ControllerBase
    {
        public async Task<string> SendMessage(string destination, string message)
        {
```

But it only works via GET, and if add the `[FROMBODY]` it stops to work, is there any workaround?

Comment: you need to have two version of this method with [httppost] and [httpget] attributes

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9552761/get-and-post-methods-with-the-same-action-name-in-the-same-controller

Comment: Will the parameters be sent in the body or URL for the POST request?

Comment: @haldo via URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could decorate the action with both `[HttpGet]` and `[HttpPost]` attributes and use `[FromQuery]` to bind the parameters (assuming POST will send the parameters in the URL too).

```
[HttpGet]
[HttpPost]    
public async Task<string> SendMessage([FromQuery]string destination, [FromQuery]string message)
{
    ...
}
```

I agree with the other answer in that `SendMessage` should really be a POST. However, if you need to access this action method using both GET and POST then perhaps this solution will work for you.

Answer (score 4):

The action SendMessage should really be a POST. GET methods should be used to retrieve data only. If you are modifiying data on the server and/or triggering an other process it should be a POST operation.

then if you need another method to retrieve messages, it should not be the same method because it is a completely different operation